# Which preposition is the right

Tags: prepositions

Which of these two sentences is correct and why?

> **By** online shopping is great that you can buy everything from the
>   comfort of your home.
>
> **On** online shopping is great that you can buy everything from the
>   comfort of your home.

Comment: You need to add more information. Specifically, why you decided to use a preposition at the start of your sentences.

Comment: I would not use neither of those, and change the sentence accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither sentence is correct, because you wouldn’t use a preposition there.

Instead, you’d say:

> Online shopping is great <strike>that</strike> **because** you can buy everything from the comfort of your home.

Comment: Yes, that seems the best option - but I suppose if the OP was determined to use a preposition, they could go for "**With** online shopping, **it** is great that you can buy everything from the comfort of your home."

Comment: @rjpond - Good point! We could also say this: *With online shopping, you can buy everything from the comfort of your home* – the “great" part can be left implied.